# How to get multiple static contexts in new CONTEXT API in React v16.6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to access multiple contexts in a component but I got success with only one context value from provider. there are two providers `ListContext` and `MappingContext. How can I access contexts like this:

```
class TableData extends React.Component {
 static contextType = ListContext;
 static contextType = MappingContext;

 componentDidMount() {
   const data = this.context // it will have only one context from ListContext
  }
```

I know I can use multiple providers in render() but I want to access the contexts like above. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One workaround is to use a wrapper that combines the two contexts into one and then export the wrapper. There are multiple ways to implement the wrapper, but here is one:

`Contexts.js`

```
import React from "react";

export const Context1 = React.createContext("1");
export const Context2 = React.createContext("2");
export const ContextCombined1And2 = React.createContext("3");
```

`ProvideCombinedContext.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Context1, Context2, ContextCombined1And2 } from "./Contexts";

// This is a reusable piece that could be used by any component that requires both contexts.
const ProvideCombinedContext = props => {
  return (
    <Context1.Consumer>
      {context1 => (
        <Context2.Consumer>
          {context2 => (
            <ContextCombined1And2.Provider value={{ context1, context2 }}>
              {props.children}
            </ContextCombined1And2.Provider>
          )}
        </Context2.Consumer>
      )}
    </Context1.Consumer>
  );
};
export default ProvideCombinedContext;
```

`Need2Contexts.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { ContextCombined1And2 } from "./Contexts";
import ProvideCombinedContext from "./ProvideCombinedContext";

class Need2Contexts extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ContextCombined1And2;
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Context=" + JSON.stringify(this.context));
  }
  render() {
    return "this.context=" + JSON.stringify(this.context);
  }
}

const WrappedNeed2Contexts = props => {
  return (
    <ProvideCombinedContext>
      <Need2Contexts {...props} />
    </ProvideCombinedContext>
  );
};

export default WrappedNeed2Contexts;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Context1, Context2 } from "./Contexts";
import Need2Contexts from "./Need2Contexts";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context1.Provider value="value1">
        <Context2.Provider value="value2">
          <Need2Contexts />
        </Context2.Provider>
      </Context1.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can see this in action and play with it here:

[image: Edit xv373l5ynz]

Comment: Thanks for detailed coding. Understood easily :)

Comment: For dynamic multiple context in Class Components refer it https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/react-multiple-contexts-class-component-vikram-gupta

Answer (score 5):

This is explained in the [React context documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype):

> You can only subscribe to a single context using this API. If you need to read more than one see [Consuming Multiple Contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts).

Comment: Yeah. But what is the workaround if I need both contexts in componentDidMount?