# React - useContext inside class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context, use-context

I'm newbie in react and i want use useContext inside my class, how do i solve this? This is example of my current code right now

```
import { Context } from '../context/ChatListContext'

const ChatList = ({ onAction }) => {
    const {state, fetchChatList} = useContext(Context)
```

And i'm expecting the same for my class

```
import { Context } from '../context/ChatListContext'

class MainScreen extends Component {

//const {state, fetchChatList} = useContext(Context) *how do i declare this?

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { loading: true, showAction: false }
    setTimeout(() => {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(primary)
    }, 100)
  }
...
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`useContext` is a hook that can't be used in a class component. For a class component you define a `static contextType`

```
import { Context } from '../context/ChatListContext'

class MainScreen extends Component {

 static contextType = Context

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { loading: true, showAction: false }
    setTimeout(() => {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(primary)
    }, 100)
  }
...
  render() {
       const {state, fetchChatList} =this.context;
  }
}
```

Comment: what if we had to consume multiple contexts?

Comment: Also note that if you need context inside a class function: `this.context.fetchChatList({});`

Comment: @CarlosCarucce There is a workaround for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53988787/10753343).

Comment: for multipple context reffer to https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts

Answer (score 4):

The contextType property on a class can be assigned a Context object created by React.createContext().

Take note of how outside the class we can assign the value of MyContext to the `Class.contextType`

You can then access all of your contexts with `this.context`

```
import MyContext from '@/context/MyContext'

class Login extends React.component() {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { four: 2*2 }
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.context);
    
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }

}

Login.contextType = MyContext
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to suggest more flexible solution for this issue

Create Wrapper component with your context:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from '../context/ChatListContext'

export const withContext = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const context = useContext(Context);

    return <Component context={context} {...props} />;
  };

  return Wrapper;
};
```

Then wrap your class in it:

```
export default withContext(MainScreen);
```

Now within this class you can access your values with:

```
this.props.context
```

You can use this approach to consume multiple contexts:

```
const contextOne = useContext(SomeContext);
const contextTwo = useContext(SomeOtherContext);
    
return <Component contextOne={contextOne} contextTwo={contextTwo} {...props} />;
```