# how to useContext in old react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to useContext in old react component? it show an empty {} when print

```
import { UserContext } from "../../firebase/user";

export class CreateProduct extends Component {
    static context = UserContext;
    render() {
        console.log(this.context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - useContext inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498035/react-usecontext-inside-class)

Comment: OP is trying to use Context within a class, not use the hook useContext.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to rename `static context` to `static contextType`. Please refer to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype):

> The contextType property on a class can be assigned a Context object created by React.createContext(). This lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using this.context. You can reference this in any of the lifecycle methods including the render function.

Answer (score 0):

> The contextType property on a class can be assigned a Context object created by React.createContext(). This lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using this.context. You can reference this in any of the lifecycle methods including the render function.

```
import { UserContext } from "../../firebase/user";

export class CreateProduct extends Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;
    render() {
        console.log(this.context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @CristianTraìna I have added it.